# gitolite: add the same config to all repos

Tags: git, gitolite

I want to auto add the same config values for all my repos managed by gitolite. I assumed that adding the following to gitolite.conf would do the trick:

```
repo @all
    config hooks.mailinglist = me@example.org
```

Although gitolite doesn't complain when I push, none of the @all config items get added to the individual repos (although any specific ones do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gitolite documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/gitolite.conf.html#_repo_specific_git_config_commands) does mention that is is a "repository specific" mechanism only, which means that groups of repository don't seem to be supported.

[The implementation](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/gitolite.pm#L406) seems to confirm that, since the comment preceding the actual `git config` states:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: next 3 subs (`setup_*`) assume `$PWD` is the bare repo itself

And that is follow by the function doing the `git config`:

```perl
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# set/unset git configs
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

sub setup_git_configs
{
    my ($repo, $git_configs_p) = @_;

    while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%{ $git_configs_p->{$repo} }) ) {
        if ($value ne "") {
            $value =~ s/^"(.*)"$/$1/;
            system("git", "config", $key, $value);
        } else {
            system("git", "config", "--unset-all", $key);
        }
    }
}
```